# Which part of my iPhone 5 screen should I take off?

Tags: hardware, iphone, screen

I'm trying to replace my iPhone 5 battery, but first I have to take my screen off. My screen appears to be glued shut on the right side, but from what I can see of the inside of it, it looks very different than the tutorials. So I'm starting to think I'm not taking off the whole screen. In the picture below, should I continue to pry #1 out, or should I pop #2 out along with #1?

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ogE8USs2Vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glass sits in the plastic guide underneath, you should focus on lifting the plastic guide first. 
Once propped slightly up, focus on the sides of the guide because there are metal clips connecting to the enclosure of the device. 
If too much pressure is applied, the plastic will break!

In other words, #2 should be your focal point.

Comment: I shouldn't just lift the whole plastic guide (#2) up?

Comment: You should lift the plastic guide up but be aware of the clips on the side of the guide as you are pulling up